# How to replace primary key in MYSQL using SED

Tags: sed

I need to replace the pattern: `\(d+,` to `(`. How can I do that?

---

Because when I exported db I need to remove the id column which is auto increment.

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (22,'xxx@gmail.com'
```

`(22,` should be replace to `(NULL,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below,

```
sed "s/([0-9]*,/(NULL,/" [file name]
```

Comment: I does not work.

Comment: Ah, the SQL is not going to work because the number of column is different.

Comment: ok, I have edited the answer and it will insert with NULL and use the automated increment value.

Comment: This makes little sense now! Perhaps one of you could modify the question as well to make more sense? As it stands, it doesn't answer the question, since it both inserts "NULL" and doesn't get rid of the comma.

Comment: @neo Thanks! And good effort to work out the real question in the first place.